# how to create unit test for function click on button

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, vitest, user-event

how to create unit test for function click on button like this [image]

i want hit the function onClickAsCard and onClickAsList , value of view is boolean from context, how i can render button with value view true or false

[image]

Comment: Don't post code as images, post it as plain text. Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide code samples as text instead of images. This way, they are not searchable and no one can c/p to try your examples.